Can cape-dabbrev be made to skip buffers of certain modes?
cape-dabbrev is part of cape. It lets you autocomplete based on the content of other buffers. This is great when all of my buffers are text files, but it's a problem when one of the buffers is something binary like a pdf.
How do I make cape-dabbrev skip checking PDF files?
I suspect that cape-dabbrev-check-other-buffers (source here) is highly relevant. However,
(setq cape-dabbrev-check-other-buffers
      (lambda () (match-buffers
          (lambda (buffer)
            (not
             (buffer-match-p
              (cons 'derived-mode 'pdf-view-mode)
              buffer))
            (buffer-list)))))

seemed to disable cape completely.

(buffer-list) should be in the outer lambda, not the inner one.

@BramSchoenmakers Hey, that works! Post it as an answer if you want.

@BramSchoenmakers I repeat my above suggestion.
